# How to get json from php to android?

Tags: android, json

i am trying to get json from php to android. i was try more and more but now my app' its not working when i press for this layout. i am really tried and search about it but the result of that search not helped me.

i want to get  some words or sentences to my layout its like how are us.

my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/how_are_us_TopTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/howRUS"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="27sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/informationAboutUS"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/how_are_us_TopTextView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
    android:text="@string/student"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/how_are_us_ButtonGoToWebsite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/informationAboutUS"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
    android:text="@string/goToWebsite"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

my php jsonGetHRSInformation

```
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
<?php

$myObj->student = "some thing like about us";


$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

echo $myJSON;
?>
```

my class

```
   private final String urlStr = "http://.... /howAreUsJson.php";

public String getData() throws IOException{
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    try {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line ;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null ){
            sb.append(line);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    catch (IOException e){

        throw  e;
    }finally {
        if( connection != null){
            connection.disconnect();
            connection = null;
        }
    }
}
```

my fragment

```
private TextView textView;
private Handler handler;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.how_are_us, null);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.informationAboutUS);
     handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    Thread runner = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            GetHRSInformation getHRSInformation = new GetHRSInformation();

            try{
                String res = getHRSInformation.getData();
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(res);
                final JSONArray informationArray = json.getJSONArray("student");

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textView.setText("student: " + informationArray);
                    }
                });


            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });


    runner.start();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its because you ar using

```
final JSONArray informationArray = json.getJSONArray("student");
```

try to use

```
final String informationArray = json.getString("student");
```

I recomend you to use Gson to parse Json and avoid to use "Thread" you should use "AsyncTask" instead

Comment: thank you , after change the code , hade some problems i was changed to `                        String res = getHRSInformation.getData();
                        final String informationArray = res.concat("student");` i have problem at php code line 4 its : `$myObj->student = "some thing like about us";`